# Send an Object and a string variable on Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, string, object

Ok, Im fairly new making Ajax calls and I wanted to know if it is possible to send more than 1 parameter in an Ajax call.

in my `$.Ajax` im sending an object and a string.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: urlAction,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(customer,telephone),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
            //Do something
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //Do something
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to send more than 1 parameter in `data`? or in this case it would be best to consider `telephone` as part of the `customer` DTO?

My `JsonResult` is trying to receive a `customer` and a `string telephone`, but telephone is null

Comment: For instance, you can send an object containing your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `JSON.stringify` you need to make sure you pass in an object. So in this instance, you could do:

`JSON.stringify({customer: customer, telephone: telephone})`

and you could pass any information you want in that object:

`JSON.stringify({customer: customer, telephone: telephone, name: 'Carl'})`

Then on your server (what ever code it is, using Ruby as an example) you could access it as:

```
params[:customer]
params[:telephone]
params[:customer][:name]
```

PHP example just for fun:

```
$_POST['customer'];
$_POST['telephone'];
$_POST['customer']['name'];
```

^ I think that's still valid PHP, it's been a few years